# SQL Referencing Key items by number(s), getting results of the number keys in a combined table

Tags: sql, t-sql, join, ssms

What join would I do to get data from a field that has 1, 2 or 3 number keys (separated with commas. Ex: 7,25) to get the corresponding values into a combined clean result (Ex. Brown, Black)?

Example:

```
TABLE_1 
Grp  ClrMix
A    6
B    7,25
C    18
D    28
E    6,7,20

TABLE_2 
ClrKeys Color
1       Blue
2       Green 
6       Red
7       Brown
18      Yellow
20      Orange
25      Pink
28      Black
```

Desired Results

```
Grp ClrMix  ColorList
A   6       Red
B   7,25    Brown, Pink
C   18      Yellow
D   28      Black
E   6,7,20  Red, Brown, Orange
```

Comment: We don't store multiple values in a single field because that's not the way that a database works. The reason you are struggling with what seems like a simple join is because you've made this mistake (or whoever built this table). You will have to parse out each value, generate a separate record for it and then join based on that result. It will not be a pretty solution and it will never be fast. I would highly suggest fixing your schema.

Comment: This is a recipe for disaster.  I suggest you normalize you database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to use `Recursive CTE`:

```
with table_1 as (
    select * from (values 
        ('A','6')
        ,('B','7,25')
        ,('C','18')
        ,('D','28')
        ,('E','6,7,20')) t(Grp, ClrMix)
)
, table_2 as (
    select * from (values       
        ('1','Blue')
        ,('2','Green ')
        ,('6','Red')
        ,('7','Brown')
        ,('18','Yellow')
        ,('20','Orange')
        ,('25','Pink')
        ,('28','Black')) t(ClrKeys, Color)
)
, rcte as (
    select
        t.Grp, t.ClrMix, iif(t.ci = 0, '', stuff(t.ClrMix, 1, ci, '')) res, cast(q.Color as varchar(8000)) ColorList, 1 i
    from (
        select 
            *, iif(ci = 0, ClrMix, left(ClrMix, ci - 1)) ind
        from
            table_1
            cross apply (select charindex(',', ClrMix) ci) ca
    ) t
    join table_2 q on t.ind = q.ClrKeys
    union all
    select
        t.Grp, t.ClrMix, iif(t.ci = 0, '', stuff(t.res, 1, ci, '')), cast(ColorList + ', ' + q.Color as varchar(8000)), i+1
    from (
        select
            *, iif(ci = 0, res, left(res, ci - 1)) ind
        from
            rcte
            cross apply (select charindex(',', res) ci) ca
        where
            len(res) > 0
    ) t
    join table_2 q on t.ind = q.ClrKeys
)

select 
    top 1 with ties Grp, ClrMix, ColorList
from 
    rcte
order by row_number() over (partition by Grp order by i desc)
```